# Is it possible to use Ruby Mechanize without Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, screen-scraping, mechanize

I wonder if is it possible to use Ruby Mechanize without Nokogiri? I never use Nokogiri explicitly.

Maybe it would be a little faster, at least the starting of the application?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use Mechanize without Nokogiri. Nokogiri is a prerequisite of Mechanize, and is how Mechanize locates the various sections inside a HTML page.

If, in code you write that uses Mechanize, you have a separate `require 'nokogiri'` statement, you can remove that line. Mechanize will still require it automatically so you don't need to do it. If you need to use Nokogiri to parse part of the document Mechanize has retrieved, you can do that via Mechanize's `page` method.